# Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime', Please use nullable types

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, casting

getting error while date is null . error line-   DateTime renewalDate = row.Field("RenewalDate");

```
protected void GrdV_Projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        DateTime renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime>("RenewalDate");
        if (renewalDate.Date > DateTime.Today)
            e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#669B1F");
        else
            e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF8234");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. The error message tells you what to do.

Comment: use nullable date-time `DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you cant convert null to date, make date-time nullable

```
 DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate")
```

also in your if statement

```
 if (renewalDate.HasValue && renewalDate.Value.Date > DateTime.Today)
```

Comment: i cannot use var . im using 3.5 framework@user5114524

Comment: DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate");
                    if (renewalDate > DateTime.Today)
                        e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#669B1F");
                    else


is it correct?

Comment: you need to consider null value in your if stmt

Comment: change if : `if (renewalDate.HasValue && renewalDate.Value.Date > DateTime.Today)`

Answer (score 5):

The error is pretty clear I think. You can't assign a NULL value to a `DateTime`. You have two options:

1. Make the field `NOT NULL` in the DB to ensure it *cannot* return `NULL`.
2. Use a `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`:

   `DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your datetime deceleration

```
 DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate");
```

Comment: Error 25 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referenence@sanu

Comment: @krishnamohan - you can use `renewalDate.Value.Date`, but first check `renewalDate.HasValue` to see if you really *have* a value.

Answer (score -1):

i have wrote this if any wrong please suggest me . for null exception checking

```
 protected void GrdV_Projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {


                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
                  //  DateTime renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime>("RenewalDate");
                    DateTime? renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("RenewalDate");
                    if (renewalDate > DateTime.Today)
                        e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#669B1F");
                    else
                        e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF8234");

                }



        }
    }
```